# Is there any thread-safe PULL queue implementation for PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any thread safe queue implementation for PHP that would allow me to put N elements into that queue, and PULL elements one by one on demand?

I need to distribute a pool of tasks between multiple users, so tasks would be fetched on request basis. I thought that messaging brokers like AMQ would fit my needs, but those are typical PUSH solutions.

Comment: Beanstalkd maybe?

Comment: You can try [splqueue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php) class on PHP.